# Sqlite query only displaying the last column's data

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database from which i want to show the data in groups. But the sqlite is showing only the data of last column. My code is as follows:

```
        String q="Select * from events";

        Cursor m = eventsDB.rawQuery(q, null);


            if(m.moveToFirst() )
                while(m.moveToNext()){
            {
            String curevent = m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String curdate = m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("date"));

            evname.setText(curevent);
            }

            }
            else {
                evname.setText("Not found");


            }
```

how can i display all the data?

Comment: use a ListView and SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: @Rahi M. you are have updated the value of curevent to last name and you are setting it to textview. Its not a error its Logical error

Comment: can it be done with TextView? or i need to move into list view? How can i convert it to list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this  if you want to set all the names to a single textview.

```
  String q="Select * from events";

    Cursor m = eventsDB.rawQuery(q, null);
        String allnames="";
         String abc[]={"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
        int q=0
        if(m.moveToFirst() )
            while(m.moveToNext()){
        {
        String curevent = m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String curdate = m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("date"));

        abc[q]=curevent;

        allnames=allnames+abc[q];
        evname.setText(allnames);
        q++
        }

        }
        else {
            evname.setText("Not found");


        }
```

Comment: @RahiM. change it to evname.setText(allnames);

Comment: It fetching all data but not in a separated way. that means it is showing all names first then all date. I want such a way that one name and one date then another name and another date.

Comment: @RahiM. use Listview to display them separately

Comment: Actually i dont know how to implement list view.

Answer (score 0):

That is what you are telling Android to do. You are looping through all the rows on the `Cursor` and at the same time setting the text; the last one is the one it is going to show since it is the last row in the `Cursor`

Answer (score 0):

> **how can I display all the data?**

Use this method to fetch all data from your table

```
public String getAllData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { name, date };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(table_name, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String someresult = "";
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(name);
    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(date);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        someresult += c.getString(iName ) + "\n" + c.getString(iDate )
                + "\n";
    }

    return someresult;
}
```

where name and date are your column names and `ourDatabase` is the instance of `SQLiteDatabase` class.

If you have more columns then add the column names in String array then fetch each indexes and fetch all data through getString().